# Total number of empty boxes

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

If you randomly put 18 balls into 10 boxes, what is the expected number of empty boxes?

I tried the following:

Let
$X_{i} = {1}$ if i-th box is empty

$X_{i} ={0}$ otherwise

Then, let $Y$ be No. of empty boxes

$Y = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ which is the total number of empty boxes. I am unable to think of $P(X_{i} = 1)$ to give $E(X_{i})$ and hence $E(Y)$

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that one ball doesn't go into a given box is $9/10$, so the probability that all $18$ balls don't is $P(X_i=1)=(9/10)^{18}$.

Comment: Thank you. I realize this is a very simple question, however I am somehow not able to arrive at the very basic result $9/10$. I'm getting confused when considering the probability of something in one group (the balls) going into another group (the boxes).

Comment: @Jojo: You may want to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference. I was using an assumption that seemed to be implied in your question, namely that the boxes are all the same and the balls are all the same and so from the principle of indifference the probability for a given ball goes into a given box is the same for all balls and all boxes. Summing this probability for a given ball over all boxes must yield $1$, since this is the sum over mutually exclusive and exhaustive possibilities (the ball goes into exactly one box).

Comment: Thus $10$ times the probability of a given ball going into a given box is $1$, so this probability is $1/10$. Then, again since the events of the ball going into the various boxes are mutually exclusive, the probability of the given ball not going into a given box, which is the probability of it going into any of the $9$ other boxes, is $9\cdot\frac1{10}=\frac9{10}$.